# Linear programming: proof of existence of optimal basic feasible solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am working through a proof outlined in section 4.4 of *Operations Research: Applications and Algorithms*, by Wayne L. Winston. The objective is to show that if a linear program has an optimal solution, then at least one of its basic feasible solutions must be optimal.

Assume:

- $x$ is an optimal solution to the linear program,
- $c^{\top} x$ is the value of the objective function at $x$,
- $b_{1} \dots b_{k}$ are the basic feasible solutions to the linear program,
- $b_{max}$ is the basic feasible solution that has the largest objective function value $c^{\top}b$ out of all $\{b_{1} \dots b_{k}\}$,
- and that the problem is bounded (i.e. $c^{\top} d = 0$ for a direction of unboundedness $d$).

Based on the fact that we can represent all feasible points of the linear program as a convex combination of the basic feasible solutions:
$$(\sigma_{i} \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_{i} = 1) \implies x = d + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sigma_{i} b_{i}$$
and based on bullet point five, we get:
$$c^{\top} x = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_{i} c^{\top} b_{i}$$

Then somehow, due to the properties of coefficients of the convex combination, it follows that:
$$c^{\top} b_{max} \geq c^{\top} x$$

at which point the proof is done. But this final step is not obvious to me. How is it valid to use $\sigma_{i} \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_{i} = 1$ as evidence of the inequality?

Comment: If all the $c^Tb_i$ are lower than $c^Tx$, then $ \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_i c^{\top} b_i <  \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_i c^Tx = c^Tx$ which contradicts.

Comment: See it this way: if a value is a (weighted) average of other values, then it can't be greater than all the other values.

Comment: That makes sense – if you post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.